Saussure says meaning is defined negatively, but is it equivalent to including context?
In this course lecture We discuss signs and meaning:
"Saussure says: Language is a system of interdependent terms in which the value of each term results
solely from the simultaneous presence of the others as in the diagram, [just below it]… In other words,
the value of a term--I say something, I utter a sound--the
value of that sound cannot be determined except by its
context. I can't know it except by the way in which it differs from
everything that surrounds it. He goes on to say--this is on page 847 about halfway down the left-hand column: … [A] segment of language can never in the final analysis be based on anything except its non-coincidence with the rest."'
De Saussure says that the "meaning" of a word can change based on the context, so meaning must come from the "negative" in relation to the context, ie what is "not", rather than a "positive" attribution to the word. The example of a stop light is given:
- {red light in recording studio}, red light means "in progress"
- {red light in traffic lights}, red light means "stop"
- {red light on christmas tree}, red light meaningless, decorative

Another example might be the word Yeah:

yeah : means yes
yeah right : means "I disagree"

Because the meaning changed completely but the sign stayed the same, the meaning must come from the other stuff.
However I think that if you alter the light to some other colour, this would change the meaning. Thus the red-light itself does contain at least some positive "meaning". I don't think it's very important to consider this as a "negative definition" of meaning.
I think an equivalent statement might be to say that the context can never be removed, and it does not make sense to separate the "red light" as I did above I.e. the minimum unit must be the whole context.
- {red light + recording studio} = recording in progress
- {red light in traffic lights} = "stop state"
- red light = ... nothing

This creates an alternate "positive definition" I think.

Red light in a recording studio (or rather: outside the door to a recording studio) also means ‘stop’ – it’s the reason why that’s different. In a traffic light, it means ‘stop, because you’ll hit someone’; at the studio, it means ‘stop, because you’ll interrupt a recording session’.

I am just using the example from the lecture. I added another example. It is certainly a true property of sign systems that meanings depend on context. Perhaps you can come up with a better one.

I don't think that positive/negative means much with regard to meaning and Saussure. What does have meaning for him is the contrastive value of signs as signifiers. A minimum unit in Saussure is not the same as context. A minimum unit is of sound.

Based solely on the exposition here it seems your interpretation, if not Saussure himself, means little more than 'context matters more than you might think…' Is that too simple?
In the given example 'I say something, I utter a sound…' it might be true that the value cannot be determined except by context, and in other cases it might not.
Saussure might be unable to know the value except as it differs from everything that surrounds it and if 'difference' is the main point, it needs much more discussion elsewhere.
Most people I know work on coalescence, not difference of meaning - unless some specific context demands otherwise.
That's why so many people come out with things like 'Yes, yes, no… (whatever)…' or 'No, no, yes… (whatever)…'.
The context of'(whatever)' over-rides any query about 'difference.'
Without trudging through 847 pages, I suggest  many and prolly most 'segments of language' can readily be understood through other means than their 'non-coincidence with the rest…'
Who doubts that might provide some useful examples…
Further, who doubts, the meaning of a word can change through context or more usefully, that forces meaning to come from the negative?
Your - or Saussure's - examples of the meaning of 'stop lights' seem self-contradictory, at best.
If {red light in recording studio} really means merely 'in progress' then its face value is as you say… not 'Stop!' or 'Do not enter!'
Similarly, who here can name anyone who doesn't see {red light on Christmas tree} as meaning 'Look at me and take joy (however cold and dark might be the night outside)'?
Another example might be the word 'Yeah.' Punctuated rightly, 'Yeah, right…' might have meant 'I disagree…' or any of several other negative forms. Since it wasn't, it just as likely means 'Yeah (with emphasis).'
'Because the meaning changed completely but the sign stayed the same…' translates usefully how, please?
Whether it's your own or Saussure's idea that
altering the light to another colour would change the meaning, who could doubt that? Is red green, or even amber?
Who doubts the red-light contains the positive meaning, 'Stop!'?
We could argue until the cows come home about whether clauses/ commands/ instructions/ phrases/ statements such as 'Stop!' are negative because of their content or positive because of their form and I suggest that's a different topic.
That context can never be removed, by no means makes that an equivalent statement.
I, for one, missed how you separated the red light above or how if you had, that might have meant the minimum unit must be the whole context.

Uh… what? Are you hoping to reported as a vexatious actor, or what?
